# How to get the new start and end on a timeline represented in pixels after zooming and/or panning

Tags: javascript, math, zooming

I'm using highcharts but can't use their built in pinch zoom stuff because it doesn't expose the correct actions I need so I'm relying on investigating the series element and transform attribute to pull off a touch zoom/pan event.  I've got the reading of the information correct, but my math skills aren't apparently up to the task of interpreting it correctly.

So given a known time period `startMs1` and `endMs`, a width those are applied over `width`, a known starting offset `startoffset`, I'm trying to calculate the ending start and time given an ending offset `endoffset` and scale `scale` where a scale > 1 is zooming in, and a scale < 1 is zooming out.

I hope this gif helps you understand the problem?

[image: Zoom And Pan]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any reason why you want this? Or may be I don't understand your question. But zoom is just multiplying everything by `zoom`, to get the actual value we can just divide by `zoom`.

You can use ratio as well.

```js
var 〱 = document.querySelector.bind(document); 
var 卐 = window.getComputedStyle;
var ლ = parseInt;

var zoom = 1.3;

var widthOfTimeline = ლ(卐(〱('#timeline')).width, 10);
var widthOfTimelineZoomed = ლ(卐(〱('#timelineZoomed')).width, 10) * zoom;
//wZoomed / woriginal = wOriginal / x
//x = wOriginal * wOriginal/ wZoomed
console.log(widthOfTimeline * widthOfTimeline/ widthOfTimelineZoomed);

//zommed timeline's 200 units = 200units/ zoom in real timeline
console.log(widthOfTimeline / zoom);
```

```css
#timeline, #timelineZoomed{
  width: 200px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  margin:20px 5px;
  }

#timelineZoomed{
  zoom: 1.6;
  }
```

```html
<div id="timeline"></div>
<div id="timelineZoomed"></div>
```